# How to get value and count if it appears next 3 consecutive times

Tags: mysql

I have table with 3 columns, now how find value if it appears next 3 times immediately

i.e 1st `trnas_value` appears in next 3 consecutive times (repeaded 4 times)
and 2nd and 6th also rows also repeated the same

```
date               tran_val                name
23mar                22                    mark
24mar                22                    mark
25mar                22                    mark
26mar                22                    mark
27mar                22                    mark
28jan                99                    john
29jan                99                    john
30jan                99                    john
31jan                99                    john
```

output

```
name     trans_value        consecutive_count
mark       22                   2
john       99                   1
```

Comment: What do you mean by next 3 times? The order is not specified and the default order that records are returned in / displayed in is not consistent. It would be possible if the data is meaningful for the order they are returned in.

Comment: @kickstart next 3 times means 1st and 2nd value repeating 3 times

Comment: i.e 1st value 22 is repating in 3 times in 2,3,4th rows and if u take 2nd value 22 is also repaeting in 3,4,5th rows but 3rd value is not repating next 3 times

Comment: The important part is _next_ 3 times. Without specifying an order there is no way of knowing whether items are consecutive or not. That 1st value of  22 might be repeated 5 other times, but which rows it is repeated on is effectively random.

Comment: it is based on dates column and my dates column is sorted from A-Z

Answer (score 1):

Basic way to do it is to add a sequence number, ordering by the field that contains the relevant order.

I am not sure about the counts, but the easiest way seems to be to just subtract 3 from the consecutive count.

```
SELECT name, 
        tran_val, 
        MAX(cnt - 3) AS consecutive_count
FROM
(
    SELECT date, 
            tran_val, 
            name, 
            @cnt:=IF(@tran_val=tran_val AND @name=name, @cnt + 1, 1) AS cnt,
            @tran_val:=tran_val,
            @name:=name
    FROM some_table
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt:=0, @tran_val:=0, @name:='') sub0
    ORDER BY `date`
) sub1
GROUP BY name, 
        tran_val
```

Comment: name tran_val consecutive_count
john           99                -1
mark   22            0         this i am getting the output

Comment: When I try it with your original data I get the output you do (I am taking it that the column of dates is a DATE type column)